# SQL query to retrieve column name among 3 columns in table whose values are mutually excluse ie.one among them will be 'Y' whose col name to be found

Tags: sql, t-sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a query in which multiple joins and select from various tables are used. One table structure is as follows: Only one column among 3 will have the value 'Y'.

Table employee :

| id | valid | invalid | non-scope |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Y | null | null |
| 002 | null | Y | null |
| 003 | null | null | Y |

The o/p of the select statement for the multiple joins and tables should have only one value from the above table and that will be the column name of this table. The value has to be as below, column name of corresponding 'Y' value :

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | valid |
| 002 | invalid |
| 003 | non-scope |

Please suggest a solution !!

Comment: You've tagged both SQL Server and Oracle - which is it?

Comment: @DaleK, its oracle

Comment: Then please remove the SQL server tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `case`

```
select id, case 'Y' 
      when valid then 'valid'
      when invalid then 'invalid'
      when [non-scope] then 'non-scope'
   end value
from employee
```

Answer (score 1):

Certainly Serg's CASE is the way to go  +1

Just for fun, here is an option that will dynamically unpivot your data

Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tPpDuKHu)

```
Select A.ID
      ,Value = B.[Key]
From   YourTable A
Cross Apply ( Select * 
               From  OpenJson((Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper ))  
               Where [Key] not in ('id','OtherCol')
            ) B
```

**Results**

```
ID   Value
001  valid
002  invalid
003  non-scope
```

Comment: Thank you for an alternative solution !!